# remove decimal in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a number: 466.62 as a double and can't change it to a string, how can I get rid of the decimal point and print 46662? I've managed to get 46662.0 by multiplying the value by 100, but I don't want to print the decimal point. Thanks

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you multiply 466.62 by 100, your end result will remain a double as well. This is why you are seeing 46662.0. So you need to convert it to Int value, so instead you should do it like this:

```
double vDouble = 466.62 *100
String vString = vDouble.toInt().toString();
```

This will give you 4662.

For a more generic case, use the String [split method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html);

```
String str = '466.62';

//split string
var arr = str.split('.');

print(arr[0]); //will print 466
print(are[1]); //will print 62
```

Comment: Didn't think of creating the variable first and then adding .Int(), of course!

Comment: or just call `.toInt()` and it will truncate all the decimal

Comment: or you can use ```var arr = str.split('.').first;```

Answer (score 6):

After you have managed to get this 46662.0,

Use this :

> `46662.0.toStringAsFixed(0);`

> `print(46662.0.toStringAsFixed(0));` - *This gives 46662*

> `print(46662.0.toStringAsFixed(0).runtimeType);` - *This gives as String.*

Reference :
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html

Comment: toStringAsFixed rounds numbers, so I do not think your answer is correct for his purpose

Answer (score 2):

You can do integer division by 1 and then turn it into a string

```dart
final String number = ((466.62 * 100) ~/ 1).toString();
```

Or just truncate

```dart
final String number = (466.62 * 100).truncate().toString();
```

More on the ~/ operator https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html

Answer (score 1):

To remove decimals from use **effective integer division**

```
int x =  (12345679.900 ~/ 1000)
```

`~/`  is *effective integer* operator and *removes decimals* .